# How can we check if Simulate.change method is working when testing a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to test a react component which takes in input and fires off events whenever the value is changed. I pass it a client and a callback to call when the value is changed.

I'm testing this by using mocha and using react's TestUtils. Here is the component :

```
var React = require('react');

var SearchBar = React.createClass({
    handleChange : function(event){
        var algoliaClient = this.props.client;
        // call algoliaClient.search with event.target.value
        // this returns a promise on which .then is called 
        // with a function which calls the onSearch callback
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="search-bar">
                <input id="search-bar" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = SearchBar;
```

In order to test this I wrote the following test :

```
describe('SearchBar', function(){
it('Sets searchResults state variable on input', function(){
    require('es6-promise').polyfill()
    var React = require('react/addons');
    var SearchBar = require('../app/components/SearchBar.js');
    var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

    var mockSearchResults = {};

    var mockSearch = function(mockData) {
        var mockPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            resolve(mockData);
        });

        return mockPromise;
    };

    var mockAlgoliaClient = {
        search : mockSearch
    };

    var mockSetState = function(data){
        mockSearchResults = data;
    }

    // Rendering component into the testdom
    var searchBar = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <SearchBar client={ mockAlgoliaClient } onSearch={ mockSetState } />
    );
    debugger;

    var input = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(
        searchBar, 'input'
    );

    assert.equal( Object.keys(mockSearchResults).length, 0 );

    TestUtils.Simulate.change(input, {target : {value : 's'}});
    debugger;

    assert.equal( mockSearchResults , {data : 's'});
});
});
```

At the end of the `Simulate.change` call, the value of `mockSearchResults` is still the same.

Comment: If client.search returns a promise, you would have to wait for that promise to resolve to check the new value of mockSearchResults

Comment: @Crob, how can I do that in the test though ?

Comment: Don't make mockPromise an actual promise.  Just return an object with a "then" function, so that client.search.then will happen synchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured how to go about testing functionality involving external api calls or any other function calls to be made my using [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/).

So for example if I wanted to mock the search call being made

```
var mocksearch = sinon.mock(algoliaclient).expects("search").
                   .once()
                   .returns(Promise.resolve(
                     { results : "test" }))
```

Passing in the `done` callback to the `it` method and calling it in the `.then` function and using a assertion framework that supports assertions with promises ensures that the tests run smoothly.